# Merge tags [appmaker] and [google-app-maker]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

These two aren't used differently and it would make the most sense to merge them to prevent duplication and confusion.

[appmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appmaker) is a more popular tag, but [google-app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-maker) fits with the same format as most other Google APIs and services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was some kind of a hard decision to make, because I usually leave the tag with the company name intact and merge the other (just in case someone else creates a product with the same name), but in this case, the tag wiki of [google-app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-maker), was not upto the mark.

So I went through most of the questions tagged [appmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appmaker) and made sure that they were all related to the Google one, and then merged them. Around 450 questions had both the tags already, and 163 ones just had the [google-app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-maker). I also added [google-app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-maker) as a synonym, in order to prevent it from being recreated.

Update: Since the top users in the tag wanted the tag to be the other way round for both intuitiveness and consistency, I swapped the synonyms, renamed the tag, and remerged the questions. The change will be reflected in a few minutes.

Comment: You kept the inferior tag, for some reason. I think you should have made the base tag be `google-app-maker`, and updated its tag wiki if needed. I don't care about this very much, but I wondered why the tag name had changed to a "worse" version.

Comment: Yeah, I am also not quite satisfied with the present tag name. I always leave the tag with the company name intact, but didn't do it this time because of the tag wikis.. Anyway, if the top users like you, prefer to have it the other way round, I can swap it in a minute. Give me 15 minutes to finish my food, and I will rename it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I'm right, but it looks inconsistent compared to [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), etc.

Comment: Ohh, that's a good point. I didn't think about the consistency part at all. I remember those debates in the amazon world, where there were three tags, [product-name], [aws-product-name] and [amazon-product-name], and finally it was decided to keep the tag name as whatever the company was referring to it as ... I swapped, renamed, merged and synonymized the tags. It should now be the other way round.